# Data driven pages - toolbox

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages, arctoolbox

I am trying to convert regular python script to toolbox. This is the regular code which works:

```
import arcpy
strOutpath = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\New Folder"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
 mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
 pageorder = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.BR
 pageindex = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.KARTA
 pdfname = pageorder + "-" + pageindex + ".pdf"      
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, strOutpath + pdfname, resolution="300dpi", image_compression="Adaptive", jpeg_compression_quality="85", colorspace="RGB", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP")
del mxd
```

And this is the my example for script to input as script for toolbox:

```
import arcpy
strOutpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
mxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
 mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
 pageorder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
 pageindex = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
 pdfname = pageorder + "-" + pageindex + ".pdf"
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, strOutpath + pdfname, resolution="300dpi", image_compression="Adaptive", jpeg_compression_quality="85", colorspace="RGB", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP")
```

As parameters, I entered this:

```
strOutpath = FOLDER 
mxd = ArcMap document 
pageorder = field 
pageindex = field
```

And when I try to input the values, I get empty fields. There is clearly something wrong with the second code and input variables, but I don't know what.

[image: empty field for input]

**EDIT:**

When I edit my code, based on the comment ArtWork21 gave, when only output folder and mxd are user-generated, this is the code:

```
import arcpy
strOutpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
mxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
 mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
 pageorder = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.BR
 pageindex = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.KARTA
 pdfname = pageorder + "-" + pageindex + ".pdf"
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, strOutpath + '\\' + pdfname, resolution="300dpi", image_compression="Adaptive", jpeg_compression_quality="85", colorspace="RGB", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP")
del mxd
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\script.py", line 4, in <module>
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'dataDrivenPages'
Failed to execute (Script).
```

And these are my variables:

[image]
So, now I now I am just trying zo get the last one script to work, where I only enter output folder, and input mxd.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to input the values, I get empty fields"?  Also, on your last export statement you need to add slashes to the output file name path like strOutpath + '\\' + pdfname

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You cannot dynamically get the page order and index from a script tool parameter.  I would leave those two statements how you had them in the first example.

Comment: Didn't know that. I will try to edit my code now, with your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to still make the map document object from its parameter path, and make sure the data driven page is enabled and saved within the map doc, try:

```
mxdPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  # continue on
```